# How to move contents of fbox to top?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, boxes

My question is how to align things in `fbox` in general but here's the clumsy solution I came up with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

{ \fontfamily{qag}\selectfont

\fbox{\vbox to 3in {\vfil \hbox to 2.5in{
    \parbox{2.5in}{
    Cozy sphinx waves quart jug of bad milk.
    Jim quickly realized that the beautiful gowns are expensive.
    }
    } \vfil }}
}
\end{document}
```

Is this the best way to create a box of fixed dimensions? How do I move all the text to the top?

Deliberately avoiding importing packages in favor of understanding how the TeX primitives work.  If it's better... I can ask these as two separate questions.

[image]

---

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034144/latex-how-to-create-boxes-with-fixed-heights-and-widths-with-enclosed-text-th

Comment: Get rid of the first `\vfil` to move the text to the top.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes perfect.  Also does it make sense to put `pbox` inside `hbox` inside `fbox`?  they all seem to have different effects in terms of allocating the space

Comment: You should be aware that spaces after opening and closing braces can matter (as they matter after a word). You are getting an overfull hbox because of them. Use `{%` and `}%` to suppress them.

Comment: you shouldn't have `\vbox` or `\vfil` or `\hbox` they are tex primitives which have no place in a parbox

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how can I get rid of them without importing numerous libraries?  In general LaTeX makes it very difficult to align things, so I am resorting to primitives.

Comment: I don't see how using `[c]` is more difficult than using two `\vfil` to get vertical centering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\parbox` has a height argument:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont

\fbox{\parbox[c][3in]{2.5in}{Cozy sphinx waves quart jug of bad milk.
    Jim quickly realized that the beautiful gowns are expensive.}}
```

This matches the vertical alignment of the code shown in the question, to get top alignment, change `[c]` to `[t]`

Note that your suggested alternative does not work as

```
\hbox to 2.5in{
\parbox{2.5in}{...}
}
```

tries to put a 2.5in box  together with a word space to the left and right into a box of size 2.5in, this will generate an overfull box (typically of .66em) But in any case you should avoid using TeX primitives at the top level in a latex document. Sometimes they are needed in macro definitions but not here.

Comment: I'm sorry can you push the text to the top?

Comment: @johnmangual yes just change the `c` to a `t`